# Firebase Cloud Functions: TLS Certificate

Tags: node.js, firebase, security, ssl, google-cloud-functions

I'm fairly new to Firebase and Cloud Functions so please bear with me :)

I created an Express-Node backend server and have it on Cloud Functions, and I have a frontend React app that makes API calls to it.  Do I need to add any TLS certificate setup to the Express server for security, or does Functions take care of that?  Aside from this, are there any other major security issues I should watch for when using Functions?  (I'm already using the Helmet package in the backend)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions will provide an SSL certificate to secure the secure https connections made to it.

If you have other security concerns, you will need to address those in your code according to your specific needs.